# Changing footer in documentclass ltxmdf

Tags: header-footer, mdframed

In the following working example I change the footer via `\ifoot`. Is this the correct approach?

```
\documentclass[parskip=false,english,11pt]{ltxmdf}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\ifoot[]{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Test}
\blindtext[7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `ltxmdf` class is designed for typesetting documentation for the `mdframed` package and is not intended for general use. Nevertheless, it is based on the `scrartcl` class and you should check the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl?lang=en) for that class.

Comment: As said before, the class does have a very limited purpose. Setting page headers/footers is done with a package that is obsolete by now. Backwards compatibility is ensured though, so you can savelu use the commands with package `scrlayer-scrpage` as well.

Comment: @ChrisS Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @ChrisS You can answer or i add a CW answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `ltxmdf` class is based on the `scrartcl` class, and so the answer to this question is found in the KOMA-Script documentation (`texdoc scrartcl`).

Headers and footers are set with the commands that specify what text is to appear on each type of page.

The KOMA-Script classes differentiate between two 'page styles': `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`. The former appears on most pages; the latter on pages which start new chapters. Pages are also differentiated based on their numbering: 'even' pages appear on the left of a double-page spread, whereas 'odd' pages appear on the right.

On each of these four types of pages, text can be placed on the left side, on the right side, or at the centre, of either the header or the footer. There are twelve commands available for this purpose.

Each command is named after a position on a page. The first letter of the command is either `l`, `c` or `r`, indicating which side of the page the text will appear on. The second letter is either `e` or `o`, indicating whether the text is to appear on even or odd pages. The rest of the command's name is either `head` or `foot`, indicating whether the text is to appear at the top or bottom of the page.

Each command takes one mandatory argument. This argument is the text that appears on the `scrheading` (normal) pages. Each command also takes one optional argument (given before the mandatory argument). This argument, if given, specifies the text to appear in the `plain.scrheading` (chapter) pages.

**Example:** To place the text 'Quack' in the centre footer of the even numbered pages, we would use the code

```
\cefoot{Quack}
```

whereas to do the same thing but also have the word 'Squawk' appearing in the same place on the chapter pages, we would use the code

```
\cefoot[Squawk]{Quack}
```

**Disclaimer:** *The above code has not been tested.*

For more information, see §5.4 of the KOMA-Script documentation.